# Opencart: modifying email layouts

Tags: php, mysql, email, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm running Opencart Version 2.0.1.1. I need a way of editing the layout of the  **registration**  and  **order update**  email.

By this, I mean control the full layout using HTML/CSS,  not just edit the text definitions of the variables. I am aware these are located in:

`./catalog/language/english/mail/customer.php` and `../order.php` respectively.

My theme came with a custom mail for the **order** email template located in `./catalog/view/theme/theme574/template/mail/order.tpl` (see below).

I want that level of control for when the user registers and when I update the order status with a comment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
    <div style="width: 680px;"><a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $store_name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo   $store_name; ?>" style="margin-bottom: 20px; border: none;" /></a>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_greeting; ?></p>
        <?php if ($customer_id) { ?>
           <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_link; ?></p>
           <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a></p>
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Could anyone help me out here? Any tips on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, could you clarify what it is you expect from us?

Comment: For the original order, the .tpl file produces a "nice" design using HTML / CSS. For example http://postimg.org/image/ui5zaru3x/. But when a user registers or I post an update to an order, it's just plain text. I need a way to be able to edit the HTML / CSS for those emails.

Comment: These are links of customer, order files which send mail to customers and you can see Opencart used plain text (not any .tpl, like you editing) so after  adding your own .tpl to send mail, you can solve this problem or may be for god sake, Opencart will add any logical and correct way to send mail in future :P links customer (https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/Branch_2.0.1.0/upload/catalog/model/account/customer.php#L51)  order (https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/Branch_2.0.1.0/upload/catalog/model/checkout/order.php#L784)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had same problem but i used mailgun lib to send my mails and i can use html/css templates :)

if you like follow this steps:
1-download mailgun lib https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

2- you have to edit system mail system or add your function to opencart system :
(i change mail function opencart totaly)
i add this codes to */system/library/mail.php*
rename send() to oldsend() or whatever you want

```
    //extracted mailgun lib address
    require 'mailgun/autoload.php';
    use Mailgun\Mailgun;

        public function send(){
        $mg = new Mailgun("mailgunkey goeshere");
        $domain = "your domain code";

        $mg->sendMessage($domain, array(
            'from'    => $this->from , 
            'to'      => $this->to , 
            'subject' => $this->subject , 
            'text'    => $this->text , 
            'html'    => $this->html
            ));
    }
```

as a example for sending mail:

```
     $data['text_discount'] = 'text';

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/mail/welcome.tpl')) {
            $html = $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/mail/welcome.tpl', $data);
        } else {
            $html = $this->load->view('default/template/mail/welcome.tpl', $data);
        }
$mail->setTo($data['email']);
        $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->setSubject($subject);
        $mail->setHtml($html);
        $mail->send();
```

this is just basic example :)