# How to remove the model column from opencart email invoice?

Tags: php, model, opencart

I do not want to have the model column at all anywhere in the opencart admin and email etc. I removed the "model" column from `admin >> view >> template >> sales >> order_invoice.tpl`. But nothing happened, can i get any idea how to remove them in all over the area in opencart backend and frontend.

> How can i remove the "Model" column from email ?

Comment: Can post some more code on what have you tried

Comment: what you mean with **model column**? and which version of OC?

Comment: @Vixed It's opencart 2x version and the model column located at product invoice table on opencart.

Comment: @Nehal yes please provide me if you have code !

Comment: there are two columns in the file you said, `<td><b><?php echo $column_model; ?></b></td>` and `<td><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>` remove them both

Answer (score 0):

There are two columns in the file you said, `<td><b><?php echo $column_model; ?></b></td>` and `<td><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>` remove them both.

For the order summary mail remove the following lines and fix the rowspan in **catalog\view\theme\default\template\mail\order.tpl**

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_model; ?></td>
```

**and**

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
```

Also remember to delete your **vqcache** if you are using **vqmod**.

Comment: I removed both and all also remove all related files too but still showing on email.

Comment: From emai?? So we are working on the wrong files... please fix you question. I'll send you an answer asap.

Comment: Thank you but i also edited and remove this file but still showing .. (We are using Pro Email Template) if it causes issue !

Answer (score 0):

i think if you could use mailgun instead php mail function after that you can use any html template in opencart and remove model in mail.
answer for mailgun:
 [Add mailgun to opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823056/opencart-modifying-email-layouts/33916522#33916522)