# is there any email template option is opencart 2.1?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to change and add email template in opencart so is there any option or setting in admin panel, or I will have to edit files ? I would like to appreciate if someone guide me.

Comment: I think, there is no such way to set email templates like magento from admin panel. You have to edit template files

Comment: one way to add email template is add mailgun sdk to opencart
[MailGun for opencart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823056/opencart-modifying-email-layouts/33916522#33916522)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just **one** template for email. But you can change it accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Can you please guide me where from where i can change it

Comment: Yes of coarse. Are you using the default template for your site?

Comment: Yes i'm using default theme

Comment: Go to `catalog\view\theme\default\template\mail\order.tpl`. This is your order template file. You can change it as per your need.